# Find center of mass for points of unequal weight and irregular distribution in 2D

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the center of mass (*EDIT: actually wrong wording, sorry! i need the point of assumed zero mass*) for points of unequal weight and irregular distribution in 2D using MATLAB. I know similar questions have been asked before, however I was not able to find an answer to exactly my problem.

I have a set of coordinates (double) and the weight (double) corresponding to each of these coordinates.

```
For example:
x = 10.3259,  12.4323,   5020.3250,  239.5757
y = 1.3412,   750.1249,  4281.9344,  3924.3121
w = 5.2532,   21.2139,   23.0123,    49.3290
```

It is assumed that the weight of the points increase radially away from the centerpoint, which is the point I am looking for. This is experimental data, hence there is no perfect solution! [Here is a colormapped scatter](http://www0.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=78780652) of my points, where blue = lowest 'weight' (1.3), and red = highest 'weight' (19.8).

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What about interpolating your data on a thinner grid and look for the minimum?

Comment: Do you have an idea of how the weight of the points increases radially away from the centerpoint? (linear, cubic, something else)

Comment: See MATLAB's griddata to interpolate your data on a grid

Comment: My first idea will not work as the minimum will amways be your lowest weight data, but it's still a start, i'm on it

Comment: Thanks for your help BillBokeey :)
Not sure how the weight increases, but I expect something rather linear.

Comment: Now I see where you are coming from with you second question. Maybe I should try to fit a cone, Gaussian or something along those lines to the data.

Comment: A linear fit would look like [this](http://www0.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=71577659). Using the minimum seems quite promising actually.

Comment: Nice! Glad i could help

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by "the point of assumed zero mass". What is the mathematical definition of what you're trying to compute?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your x, y and w are vectors, you could just do:

```
center_of_mass_x = sum(w.*x)/sum(w)
center_of_mass_y = sum(w.*y)/sum(w)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
Using your code and not getting the correct result, I realized that I forgot a very important detail in my question, which I assume actually makes calling this a center of mass incorrect. I will update it now.